# Count the number of all specific keys (or values) in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have a large nested JSON object like this, and I want to count the number of `pets` in the whole object. How can we achieve that? I've tried `Object.keys(obj[0]).length` but have not been successful in the desired result. Also, how can I go deeper into the array for counting for example some nested value like `color` in `pet`?

What is a good tutorial for working with multi-level arrays in JavaScript or Angular?

```js
obj = [
 {
        "person": {
          "name": "a",
        },
        "pet": {
          "name": "1"
        }
      },

      {
        "person": {
          "name": "b",
        },
        "pet": {
          "name": "2",
          "color": "black",
          }
        },

      {
        "person": {
          "name": "c",
        },
        "pet": {
          "name": "3",
          "color": "red",
          }
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the array with pet property and pet's color property and perform array count.

```js
let obj = [
    {
        "person": {
            "name": "a",
        },
        "pet": {
            "name": "1"
        }
    },

    {
        "person": {
            "name": "b",
        },
        "pet": {
            "name": "2",
            "color": "black",
        }
    },

    {
        "person": {
            "name": "c",
        },
        "pet": {
            "name": "3",
            "color": "red",
        }
    }
];
let petItemCount = obj.filter(x => x["pet"]).length;
console.log(petItemCount);

let petItemWithColorCount = obj.filter(x => x["pet"] && x["pet"]["color"]).length;
console.log(petItemWithColorCount);
```

In case the `pet` value is possibly `null` or pet's `color` is possibly null,

```js
let petItemCount = obj.filter(x => x["pet"] != undefined).length;
console.log(petItemCount);

let petItemWithColorCount = obj.filter(x => x["pet"] && x["pet"]["color"] != undefined).length;
console.log(petItemWithColorCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let pets = 0;
obj.map( item => {
  if(item.pet) {
    pets += 1;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like reducing would be a fit:

```
colors = obj.reduce(
 (sum, { pet }) => pet.color !== undefined ? ++sum : sum, 
0)); // -> initial count value
```